# How can i pass a variable and some HTML using jQuery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

not sure why this doesn't work , but would like to know. When i place either individually they both produce the desired results , but i want to combine

```
var getHTML = $(data).find('.report tbody td');

$('div').html(getHTML + '<td>AddThis</td>');
```

this works

```
$('div').html(getHTML);
```

or this works , but not both combined

```
$('div').html('<td>AddThis</td>');
```

Comment: `var getHTML = $(data).find('.report tbody td').html();` - in your code getHTML is an object, so works on its own, but when combined it becomes `"[Object object]<tdAndThis</td>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created a variable named getHTMl, then you did not put the .html() method there.

```
var getHTML = $(data).find('.report tbody td').html();

$('div').html(getHTML + "<td>AddThis</td>");
```